# Springfox 3.0 not working in Spring framework

Tags: spring, swagger, springfox

I have a Spring application. I am trying to migrate it to Springfox 3.0 from Springfox 2.9.2.

It is already working on old Springfox dependencies, but with 3.0, I can't access any of the documentation at all. As far as I know, all I just need to do is add the Springfox dependecy below:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And remove all Springfox 2.9.2 configurations/beans. And it should work alright.

I tried accessing the Swagger UI docs via

```
/swagger-ui
/swagger-ui/
/swagger-ui/#/
/swagger-ui/index.html
```

Still, its not accessible. The microservice compiles successfully with mvn clean install. What do I do to make Springfox 3.0 work?

Comment: Which Spring version are you using? Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: yes Spring boot, im using <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>

Comment: Take a look at this - https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBoot-JPA_REST-CRUD-SwaggerUI/blob/main/src/main/java/spring/boot/restful/crud/swagger/config/SwaggerConfiguration.java

Answer (score 0):

You still need to keep the following basic configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class SpringFoxConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build();                                           
    }
}
```

You may want to check the migration guide [here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox#migrating-from-earlier-snapshot).

---

I strongly suggest you move to springdoc, which is a more recent library, way less buggy and much easier to work with. Take a look at:

- https://springdoc.org/
- https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox

Comment: i did tried this as I have this with my old swagger dependency, still doesnt work. I just removed the @EnableSwagger2 annotations from that config too.

Comment: Do you have `@EnableWebMvc` in your code? Additionally, I've added a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: nope, though I did add that annotation in the configuration class, still doesnt work

Comment: In that case, without any explicit error or additional code would be very hard to help you.